# python pandas create dataframe and force multiple column types

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to create dataframe and force one data type by

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1.1,2.1,3.1]}, dtype=int)
```

But I want to specify type for each column. How can I do this? I tried the following which doesn't work as the resulting dtypes are objects and b columns are not casted into integers.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1.1,2.1,3.1]}, dtype=[('a', int),('b', int)])
```

Jeff helped with above case. But I found another problem when I try to create an empty dataframe and I want to be able to specify column types. For single type across columns, I could do

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], dtype=int)
```

What if I want to specify type for each of 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: This is not supported (potentially it could take a dict), you realize that passing dtype is optional?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass in a Series which has a dtype parameter

```
In [15]: pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[1.1,2.1,3.1]}).dtypes
Out[15]: 
a      int64
b    float64
dtype: object

In [16]: pd.DataFrame({'a':Series([1,2,3],dtype='int32'), 'b':Series([1.1,2.1,3.1],dtype='float32')}).dtypes
Out[16]: 
a      int32
b    float32
dtype: object
```

Comment: next but similar question, what if I want to create an empty dataframe with specified types?

Comment: not recommended to create an empty frame at all (nor can you create it with specified types). Create the data you need, e.g. series or whatever, and just ``concat`` together or use the above method if you *really* need separate dtypes.

Comment: I guess you could use the pass-Series trick, like `dmap = {'a': 'int32', 'b': 'float64', 'c': 'int64'}; df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(dtype=v) for k,v in dmap.items()})`, but as Jeff says, starting from an empty frame is usually an antipattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a dictionary of `numpy` arrays, with specified `dtype`s; this works for creating both filled and empty arrays. (This answer is a slight adaptation on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383353/5627846).)

Here's an empty array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a' : np.array([], dtype=int),
                        'b' : np.array([], dtype=float)
                       }
                 )
```

Here's a filled_array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a' : np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int),
                        'b' : np.array([4,5,6], dtype=float)
                       }
                 )
```

And you can use basically any type for `dtype`, such as `object`, `str`, `datetime.datetime` or `CrazyClassYouDefined`. That said, if pandas doesn't specifically support a type (such as `str`), pandas will fall back to treating that column as `object`. Don't worry though, everything should still work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, good question. You can try to specify one common dtype at the time you create the dataframe or add empty numpy arrays with different dtypes. Nevertheless, my experience is that pandas tends to infer the dtype for the whole dataframe based on the data you add. I feel it is better to specify the dtypes for the various columns **after** you have added your data to the dataframe:

```
convert_dict = {'a': int, 'b': float}
df = df.astype(convert_dict)
```