# Enforce dtype on empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have an empty dataframe of format:-

> Id,startDate

The dtype of this comes out to be:-

```
Series([], Name: startDate, dtype: object)
```

How can I enforce it to treat startDate as datetime, even if the dataframe is empty

Comment: I believe you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36462257/2901002), it is dupe :(

Answer (score 1):

you can specify dtype while reading file.

```
pd.read_csv(file_name,dtype={col1:type}))
```

for more details: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)