# Importing from SQL into pandas dataframe directly as number instead of object using psycopg2

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

I can import into a dataframe like so:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=['name','ts','open','close']))
```

All df column dtypes will be of object.

I can convert them into the proper numbers after by:

```
df2=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').info()
```

Is there any way to do it on the fly where i specify the datatype without having to do multiple calculations/lines of code?

Comment: Not sure if it'd work, but can you create an empty df and import into that? see some of the more recent solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462257/create-empty-dataframe-in-pandas-specifying-column-types ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider pandas' [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) using an [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html) engine as the connection:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@/dbname")

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM myTable', con=engine)
```

Comment: is there any better alternative? `pd.read_sql()` is really slow. it takes almost doubles the time compare to `cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: @JanmejayaNanda, all depends on your environment. Please ask new question with specifications.