# Pandas: Why are my headers being inserted into the first row of my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a script that collates sets of tags from other dataframes, converts them into comma-separated string and adds all of this to a new dataframe. If I use `pd.read_csv` to generate the dataframe, the first entry is what I expect it to be. However, if I use the `df_empty` script (below), then I get a copy of the headers in that first row instead of the data I want. The only difference I have made is generating a new dataframe instead of loading one.

The `resultData = pd.read_csv()` reads a .csv file with the following headers and no additional information:

> Sheet, Cause, Initiator, Group, Effects

The `df_empty` script is as follows:

```
def df_empty(columns, dtypes, index=None):
    assert len(columns)==len(dtypes)
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
    for c,d in zip(columns, dtypes):
        df[c] = pd.Series(dtype=d)
    return df

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374031    
# Usage: df = df_empty(['a', 'b'], dtypes=[np.int64, np.int64])
```

My script contains the following line to create the dataframe:

```
resultData = df_empty(['Sheet','Cause','Initiator','Group','Effects'],[np.str,np.int64,np.str,np.str,np.str])
```

I've also used the following with no differences:

```
resultData = df_empty(['Sheet','Cause','Initiator','Group','Effects'],['object','int64','object','object','object'])
```

My script to collate the data and add it to my dataframe is as follows:

```
data = {'Sheet': sheetNum, 'Cause': causeNum, 'Initiator': initTag, 'Group': grp, 'Effects': effectStr}
count = len(resultData)
resultData.at[count,:] = data
```

When I run `display(data)`, I get the following in Jupyter:

```
{'Sheet': '0001',
 'Cause': 1,
 'Initiator': 'Tag_I1',
 'Group': 'DIG',
 'Effects': 'Tag_O1, Tag_O2,...'}
```

What I want to see with both options / what I get when reading the csv:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
| Sheet | Cause | Initiator | Group |      Effects       |
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
|  0001 |     1 | Tag_I1    | DIG   | Tag_O1, Tag_O2,... |
|  0001 |     2 | Tag_I2    | DIG   | Tag_O2, Tag_04,... |
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

What I see when generating a dataframe with `df_empty`:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
| Sheet | Cause | Initiator | Group |      Effects       |
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
| Sheet | Cause | Initiator | Group | Effects            |
| 0001  | 2     | Tag_I2    | DIG   | Tag_O2, Tag_04,... |
+-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the generated dataframe to copy my headers into the first row and if it possible for me to not have to read an otherwise empty csv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because you've inserted the first row as data. The magic behaviour of using the first row as header is in read_csv(), if you create your dataframe without using read_csv, the first row is not treated specially.

Solution? Skip the first row when inserting to the data frame generate by df_empty.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by inserting the first row as data? Do mean that the header names specified in df_empty are inserted as data instead of headers?

When I ran `resultData = df_empty(['Sheet','Cause','Initiator','Group','Effects'],[np.str,np.int64,np.str,np.str,np.str])` and then `display(resultData)` I got back a set of headers (bold with a line underneath), but no data displayed beneath the headers.

Also, if the df_empty inputs were placed as data, wouldn't they just have been overwritten? Anyways, when I skipped the first row, the index just increased by 1. Data was same.